# Angular select tooltip for text overflow

Tags: html, angularjs, select, tooltip

I have a select that looks as follows:

```
<select id="select-full"
    title="Make selection"
    class="form-control form-custom input-sm"
    name="Select"
    ng-model="form.select"
    ng-options="select.displayName as select.text for select in selects | orderBy:'text'">
    <option value="">Any</option>
</select>
```

Some of the text populated by ng-options is very long, and so I plan to have the ones that would cause overflow to have trailing ellipses.

But I wanted to know if, additionally, there is a way to make it so that mousing over one of the options within the select to have a tooltip display the full entry? So that the user could inspect the full entry before making a choice. Whether it is in the HTML or angular controller doesn't matter.

If there isn't a way, that is a fine answer, but doing some searching hadn't yielded an answer as to whether exactly what I want to do here is doable.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you did answer the question, hah. Do you know how to go about this?

Comment: Sure I can help you with all your problems, when I will be free next time :) Show us what you tried please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uib-tooltip as :

```
<span tooltip-append-to-body="true"  uib-tooltip="{{select.displayName}}" tooltip-placement="right">{{select.displayName}}</span>
```

Here `tooltip-append-to-body="true"` will move your tooltip to parent scope so that it is not chopped off in selections div.

Learn more about it on [Uib Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)